# CreateContainerError: context deadline exceeded

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, helm, rancher-2

For a project, I must use big containers (500Mb to 60Gb).

I don't have a precise measurement but when I run containers larger than 3-5Gb with gitlab-runner, I get an error in rancher: `CreateContainerError: context deadline exceeded`

Our kubernetes cluster is build with rke with rancher as web ui and located in our datacenter.

The bug only appears with gitlab-runner, if I launch `docker run ...` on the kubernetes node, everything works fine.

Maybe there is a timeout somewhere?

Have any of you ever had this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that adding these lines in my rke config (cluster.yml) resolve this issue:

```yaml
services:
  kubelet:
    extra_args:
      runtime-request-timeout: '1h'
```